# Ordering output of LIST in Snowflake

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I've been using the `LIST` command to check the files staged to a table in Snowflake. However, the data is unordered and I'd like to order it by `last_modified`. I tried embedding it into a SELECT query like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM LIST @MY_DATABASE.MY_SCHEMA.%my_table/path/to/data PATTERN = '.*[.]csv.*'
```

However, this query fails to compile. I've tried preceding `LIST` with the `CALL` keyword as well, but no luck there. I've even tried assigning it to a local variable, but that doesn't work either. The data appears to be tabular so I'm not sure why I can't work with it.

How can I query on the output of `LIST`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am personally using the following "hacky" solution:

1. Start by executing the "list" command.
2. I Then use the [result_scan](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/result_scan.html) function combined with [last_query_id](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/last_query_id.html) function to fetch the results of that query, as this point I can start querying the data, here's how it looks:

```
LIST @MY_DATABASE.MY_SCHEMA.%my_table/path/to/data PATTERN = '.*[.]csv.*'

WITH data(name, size, md5, last_modified) as (
     SELECT * FROM table(result_scan(last_query_id()))
)
select *
from data 
order by last_modified desc;
```

Obviously this is a manual hack as I retrieve the last query id, if you can't ensure this property you need to get the actual query id and use that explicitly instead.

Comment: Thanks for this. I'm not automating this but using it to monitor my staging operations in real time so this really helps.